# WebSocket frame fragmentation in an API

Tags: websocket, jetty, netty, grizzly

Would exposing a WebSocket fragmentation have any value in a client-side API?

Reading the RFC 6455 I became convinced a non-continuation frame doesn't guarantee you anything in terms of its semantics. One shouldn't rely on frame boundaries. It's just too risky. The spec addresses this explicitly:

```
Unless specified otherwise by an extension, frames have no semantic
meaning.  An intermediary might coalesce and/or split frames, if no
extensions were negotiated by the client and the server or if some
extensions were negotiated, but the intermediary understood all the
extensions negotiated and knows how to coalesce and/or split frames
in the presence of these extensions.  One implication of this is that
in absence of extensions, senders and receivers must not depend on
the presence of specific frame boundaries.
```

Thus receiving a non-continuation frame of type Binary or Text doesn't mean it's something atomic and meaningful that has been sent from the other side of the channel. Similarly a sequence of continuation frames doesn't mean that coalescing them will yield a meaningful message. And what's even more upsetting,
a single non-continuation type frame may be a result of coalescing many other frames.

To sum up, groups of bytes sent over the WebSocket may be received regrouped pretty much any way, given the byte order is the same (that's of course *in absence of extensions*).

If so, then is it useful to introduce this concept at all? Maybe it's better to hide it as a detail of implementation? I wonder if WebSocket users have found it useful in such products like Netty, Jetty, Grizzly, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragmentation is not a boundary for anything.

It's merely a way for the implementation to handle itself based on memory, websocket extensions, performance, etc.

A typical scenario would be a client endpoint sending text, which is passed through the permessage-deflate extension, which will compress and generate fragments based on its deflate algorithm memory configuration, writing those fragments to the remote endpoint as it has a buffer of compressed data to write (some implementations will only write if the buffer is full or the message has received its final byte)

While exposing access to the fragments in an API has happened (Jetty has 2 core websocket APIs, both that support fragment access), its really only useful for those wanting lower level control on streaming applications. (think video / voip where you want to stream with quality adjustments, dropping data if need be, not writing too fast, etc ...)

Comment: I wonder if WebSocket API clients really understand that. Because what it actually means is that if not streaming, one should better use some subprotocol over the WebSocket to divide the stream into meaningful chunks (e.g. RPC calls, text messages, etc.) Otherwise each time one receive something, they unknowingly roll the dice.
I suppose it's not always that one can use the hack to persuade a sever to use some unknown randomly named extension that will effectively forbid changing frame's boundaries.

Comment: In practice, no websocket implementation, websocket extension, or websocket proxy has been built assuming that frame boundaries cannot be changed. (the autobahn testsuite that the industry uses for verification of websocket implementations tests for this)

Comment: I wonder if there's a code anywhere in WebSocket infrastructure that takes two consecutive non-continuation frames `f1` and `f2` and merges them into `f12`. That might be a big surprise for those end-users who rely on boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some ambiguity in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) concerning unfragmented messages, that they can be split or combined arbitrarily. But, in the situation where a message is deliberately sent as multiple fragments (totalling X bytes), is it allowable for an intermediary to split some of these frames in a way that returns a different number (than X) of bytes in the sequence? I don't think that is allowed and fragmentation has some value in that respect. This is just from reading the RFC, as opposed to looking at real implementations.

> The fragments of one message MUST NOT be interleaved between the
>       fragments of another message unless an extension has been
>       negotiated that can interpret the interleaving.

To my reading this implies that unless some extension has been negotiated which allows it, fragments from different messages cannot be interleaved and this means that while the number of fragments can be altered, the exact number of bytes (and the bytes themselves) cannot be.

Comment: The history of that interleaving statement is for [the (then) planned mux extension that would have allowed multiplexed messages on a websocket connection](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-websocket-multiplexing-11).   The [mux extension has been abandoned](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/hybi/-aVUIRMytsrXa6yUN13mFk3bi_c) and the effort for multiplexed messages is being rolled into the HTTP/2 spec instead.

Answer (score 0):

There should be support for controlling fragmentation; We have a C# program that intentionally splits a large WebSocket message into small fragments so a small embedded processor receiving the data can process small chunks at a time. Instead it is arriving completely coalesced into a single large block consuming most of the available memory.
We are not sure where the coalescing is taking place. Maybe the C# library.